# Overwriting with a XmlTextWriter?

Tags: .net, xmltextwriter, overwrite

Simple question, how do i overwrite with a xmltextwriter?

I use   `var writer = new XmlTextWriter(exam.Path, null);`.
SO if i have a new document it writes as i should be.

But if the document already exists, how do i overwrite this document by a new document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5366y21d.aspx) states that your usage will truncate the file and overwrite it with new content.

> filename Type: System.String The
>   filename to write to. If the file
>   exists, it truncates it and overwrites
>   it with the new content.

Comment: Yes, I think with most .NET "writers" (i.e. streamwriter, etc) if you specify a file that already exists it will be overwritten automatically. Some have an "append" boolean parameter though I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite the file and find your current method appends instead you could try and delete the file in question beforehand.

e.g.

```
System.IO.File.Delete(exam.Path);
var writer = new XmlTextWriter(exam.Path, null);
```